# Have didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo perform different actions based on different senders

Tags: swift, swift2

I am wondering if there is a way to have the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method perform different actions based on the sender.

For example:

In one `ViewController` I have a camera button, that when the user finishes taking a photo, `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` would save this to the camera roll. I then have another camera button, with another purpose, on this same `ViewController`that after a user finishes taking a photo, the photo would be uploaded to my server.

I have looked into NSNotificationCenter but am not sure that this will do the trick.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your UX flow:

User taps button 1 -> user takes photo -> photo gets saved to camera roll

User taps button 2-> user takes photo -> photo gets sent to server

If that's the case, wouldn't keeping track of the `id` of the sender that the user taps to move to the camera work? In your view controller, have an ivar that is set to whichever button the user last tapped. Then, when you return from selecting media, see which button in your view controller was last tapped and select your action based on that.